# What is "insulin resistance" and why is the word "resistance" used?

Tags: insulin-resistance

"Resistance" means refusal to accept or to comply.  "Insulin resistance" seems to be a loss of efficiency or efficacy of insulin in the body --- or perhaps an excess of glucose in the blood creating problems for the body to absorb sugar and turn it into energy.

As you can see, I don't know what is insulin resistance and I also can never relate the word resistance when I look up definitions for "insulin resistance".

Comment: These seems more like a language question than a medical sciences one. There isn't a specific terminology issue here, it's the plain meaning of the word, you've just focused down on one definition of the word "resistance" rather than reading an entire dictionary definition.

Comment: Would the definition "the ability not to be affected by something, especially adversely" of "resistance" be the appropriate one for "insulin resistance"?

Comment: More simply just "less affected by something."

Answer (score 4):

Insulin resistance refers to decreased ability of insulin receptors in the cell membranes to respond to insulin.

[Insulin resistance (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin_resistance):

> Insulin resistance implies that the body's cells (primarily muscle)
>   lose sensitivity to insulin, a hormone secreted by the pancreas to
>   promote glucose utilization. At the molecular level, a cell senses
>   insulin through insulin receptors...